# Сортировка map по значению

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Есть `HashMap<String, Integer>`, можно ли сделать первичную сортировку по типу String?

Comment: Использовать [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) вместо `HashMap`?

Comment: Если хотите сортировку, то используйте TreeMap, если хотите сортировку по мере записи в мапу, то используйте LinkedHashMap

Comment: Спасибо, LinkedHashMap помогло. С TreeMap пробовал, есть небольшие проблемы - он помимо первого параметра сортирует также и второй

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с LinkedHashMap

```
 Map<String, Integer> result = unsortMap.entrySet().stream()
                    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                            (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```